# hive-drop-import-delims not removing newline while using HCatalog in Sqoop

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop, hcatalog

Sqoop while used with HCatalog import not able to remove new line (\n) from column data even after using  --hive-drop-import-delims option in the command when running Apache Sqoop with Oracle.

Sqoop Query:

```
    sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ORA_IP:ORA_PORT:ORA_SID \
--username user123 --password passwd123 -table SCHEMA.TBL_2 \ 
--hcatalog-table tbl2 --hcatalog-database testdb --num-mappers 1 \ 
--split-by SOME_ID --columns col1,col2,col3,col4 --hive-drop-import-delims \
--outdir /tmp/temp_table_loc --class-name "SqoopWithHCAT" \
--null-string ""
```

Data in Oracle Column **col4** as below: (Data has control characters such as ^M)

```
<li>Details:^M
    <ul>^M
        <li>
```

Does Control character causing this problem?

Am I missing anything ? Is there any workaround or solution for this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `--map-column-java` option to explicitly state the column is of type `String`. Then `--hive-drop-import-delims` works as expected (to remove `\n` from data).

Changed Sqoop Command :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ORA_IP:ORA_PORT:ORA_SID \
--username user123 --password passwd123 -table SCHEMA.TBL_2 \ 
--hcatalog-table tbl2 --hcatalog-database testdb --num-mappers 1 \ 
--split-by SOME_ID --columns col1,col2,col3,col4 --hive-drop-import-delims \
--outdir /tmp/temp_table_loc --class-name "SqoopWithHCAT" \
--null-string "" --map-column-java col4=String
```

Comment: I had a column with data type CLOB so i used --map-column-java to convert it to string then both hive-drop-import-delims and --hive-delims-replacement "|"  worked

Answer (score 5):

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ORA_IP:ORA_PORT:ORA_SID \
--username 123 \
--password 123 \
--table SCHEMA.TBL_2 \
--hcatalog-table tbl2 --hcatalog-database testdb --num-mappers 1 \
--split-by SOME_ID --columns col1,col2,col3,col4 \
--hive-delims-replacement "anything" \
--outdir /tmp/temp_table_loc --class-name "SqoopWithHCAT" \
--null-string ""
```

You can try this --hive-delims-replacement "anything" this will replace all \n , \t , and \01 characters with
the string you provided(in this case replace with string "anything").

Comment: Both --hive-delims-replacement "null" and --hive-drop-import-delims did not work untill --map-column-java col4=String was added. That mean whichever column you want delims switch to work, it has to be java String type.

Comment: How can I do the same if I need to dump data into HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

From the official website:
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html

> Hive will have problems using Sqoop-imported data if your database’s rows contain string fields that have Hive’s default row delimiters (\n and \r characters) or column delimiters (\01 characters) present in them. You can use the --hive-drop-import-delims option to drop those characters on import to give Hive-compatible text data. Alternatively, you can use the --hive-delims-replacement option to replace those characters with a user-defined string on import to give Hive-compatible text data. These options should only be used if you use Hive’s default delimiters and should not be used if different delimiters are specified.